# Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 : I \to M$ two homotopic curves, $M$ a $C^{\infty}$ manifold. If $\omega$ is a closed $1-$form then:

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 : I \to M$ two homotopic curves, $M$ a $C^{\infty}$ manifold. If $\omega$ is a closed $1-$form then:

$$\int_{\gamma_1(I)} \omega = \int_{\gamma_2(I)}\omega.$$

Then, conclude that $H^1(M) = 0$ if $M$ is simply connected.

I saw this claim on a book of topologic degree theory, and I was not able to prove. I do appreciate any help!

Comment: Hint: Pullback the homotopy $H:I \times I \to M$ and use Stoke's theorem.

Comment: You need $M$ to be orientable I think.

Comment: @Hmm. Why? The curves are automatically oriented.

Comment: @TedShifrin, yes that indeed is enough. My bad.

Comment: @Max, you are saying to me do the pullback by the homotopy function?

Comment: Yes. Pullback $d\omega$ to $I \times I $ by $H $ and apply Stoke's. At that stage you will be nearly done. Also @Hmm., note that simply connected manifolds are orientable, since nonorientable manifolds have path connected double covers, so for the sake of the conclusion we do have an orientable manifold.